# Misled, passive or active?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering which one sounds more natural to native English speakers.which one is more appropriate. passive or active?

> John misled me.
>
> I was misled by John.

Comment: Without more context this can't be answered. The two sentences are equivalent in meaning. There may be a reason to use the passive, but you haven't provided any context that could give a reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a minor difference between the two. The first places some emphasis on the fact that it was John who misled you.  The second places some emphasis on the fact that you were misled, and that it was john who did so.

The first sentence is in the active voice and the second is in the passive voice.  It makes little difference which of these two sentences you use as they both clearly identify the subject and object of the action. The second sentence could be changed to:

> I was misled.

This sentence highlights a common reason for using the passive voice, i.e. obscuring the identity of the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. I think "John misled me" is more of an exclamation or explanatory phrase you might find in a conversation between two people.
The phrase "I was misled by John" would be more common to find in a reflective context such as an account of events.